# How do I call a bat file from command prompt which will run a python file?

Tags: python, batch-file, command-prompt

So I want to create a custom command in command prompt. For example:

```
C:\Users\User> create Helloworld
```

Where `create` will be the custom command which will run a batch script to run a python file and pass the string `Helloworld` to the python file.

I'm new to batch files. Any help is appreciated. Have a great and safe day! Thanks for reading!

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `call /?` and read the output help. So if you create, for example, in directory `%SystemRoot%` (`C:\Windows` in most cases) a batch file `create.bat` or `create.cmd` with, for example, `@python.exe "C:\Full Path\ScriptFile.py" %*`, then you have what you want.

Comment: I created a answer on something similar called `please` will see if I can do something for you like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
Call x:\path\yourPyBtachCaller.cmd "%*"
```

And place this create.cmd in any of the folders in your %PATH%